# Unable to get with my PHP Code Wikipedia infobox json pages key with its short description

Tags: php

I am trying to extract with `json_decode`, the full wikipedia infobox content of all the `pages` json key from the `https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=twitter&rvsection=0` page with my PHP code below:

```
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=twitter&rvsection=0";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $data = current($data['query']['pages']);
    $shortDescription = $data[0];
    echo $data;
```

But, I get the following error:

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\laragon\www\test3.php on line
> 57 Array

And when I also do an `echo $shortDescription;` instead of: `echo $data;`, I get another kind of error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\laragon\www\test3.php on line 57

So how can I correct my code to extract into a `$data` variable in **HTML** form all the content of the `pages` key containing the infobox information and into the `$shortDescription` variable, the very first sentence (i.e. the text of the **Short Description** which is: *American social networking service*) ???

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the first problem, you can't echo an array, you can try to use a print_r  to see the value of $data or you can access the elements directly.

```
$url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=twitter&rvsection=0";
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
$data = current($data['query']['pages']);

echo $data['title']; //access an element

print_r($data); //see the response value
```

The second error is because the array stored in $data don't have a index 0, it's a key value array (hash), so you need to access the elements using the correct keys.